# Get a precise character of a textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouse, textblock

I would like to know if there were any way to get the character which is directly pointed out by the mouse in a TextBlock.

I've found how to do this using a TextBox by using the following code :

```
 private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            Point p = e.GetPosition(t);

            int val =  t.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(p, true);    

            txtResult.Text = t.Text[val].ToString() ;
        }
```

but it seems that the TextBlock doesn't have any similar method.

Does anyone have an idea?

KiTe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no ready-made features such as `GetCharacterIndexFromPoint()` for `TextBlock`, I can advise to use a `Style` for `TextBox` that simulates the behavior of the `TextBlock`.

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockBehavior" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
</Style>

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBehavior}" Text="Sample" Width="100" Height="30" MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove" />
```

Perhaps it will be easier to implement functions such as `GetCharacterIndexFromPoint()` for `TextBlock`.

Comment: This is the solution I came up after a while. So it really looks like there is no other way :( thank you